# Can I move files in a pending Add operation?

Tags: tfs

I have a large number of new files which need to added into our TFS codebase (since I'm integrating a third-party library). I have used the shell extension to Add the top-level folder, and spent a fair bit of time weeding out files we don't need. All the files are showing as a pending Add in my Pending Changes.

It's now been suggested by the project's architect that the server path I've picked for the new files isn't ideal.

Is it possible to move the files an have the pending Add follow along? Or am I reduced to either undoing the add, moving the files and redoing the add; or checking in, then doing a `tf rename`?

Answer (score 1):

Totally possible.  Just click on the files/folders in Source Control explorer (or use the shell extension) and do a move.  #JustTestedThisOut
Or just add, then move.  It'll be in the history, but that's rarely an issue unless you have **very** tight auditing requirements.

Comment: Just tried this myself. I can move a _file_ that's been added but not checked in; but I can't move the top-level folder. (In the end, I undid the add, moved, and redid it).